# Is hydrogen atom in a box solvable analytically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential, hydrogen

Schrödinger's equation for hydrogen atom in free space can be easily solved by switching to center of mass frame, introducing reduced mass and separating variables in the resulting 3D problem. But what if we confine electron and proton to some sort of a box with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions?

Is there any shape (cubic, spherical, any shape with finite diameter) for such a box, which would allow the problem to be solved analytically — or at least separate the variables so as to get a finite set of ODEs?

Comment: hi! Assume a spherical, perfectly reflecting mirror centered on the H nucleus - see figure in the picture. Is this problem solvable. The boundary conditions should be that the wave-function vanishes on the mirror. Since the atom is neutral, I assume that no charges appear on the mirror surface - am I right? I don't see a reason why the Schrodinger equation shouldn't be separable by variables. Do you see such a reason?

Comment: Do you mean a box around the proton, or a box that both particles bounce around in? For the former, a spherical box will give the spectrum in terms of the zeros of Laguerre polynomials. The latter will entangle the relative motion with the COM motion, which will not be analytically treatable.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty : good question, box around the atom, not around the nucleus. I rely on that the atom is neutral (I hope that I can rely on this) otherwise on the internal side of the mirror will appear a negative charge and the things will complicate.

Comment: @Sofia Note that the 'wall' in the OP is a surface at which homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions (i.e. $\psi=0$) apply. A real mirror will be much more complicated and you *will* have interactions, even for a neutral atom; these are known as Casimir-Polder interactions.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty : very well, then what you suggest? Please fill free to replace my suggestion, and I will adapt the picture.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty do you think of a dielectric?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty : by the way, why shall we care of the Casimir-Polder interactions? Mirrors are always used to reflect wave-functions.

Comment: @Sofia I'm not sure what you want, but it would probably be best for you to start a new question with exactly what you're looking for, so that this doesn't override the OP's question.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty this question is not mine, it is of Ruslan. I was just thinking of a solution to what he asks. He wants to introduce the atom in a box and asks if the Schrodinger eq. can have a solution, and which type of box is better. It seems to me obvious that spherical box, and with walls that impose boundary cond. zero. This is why I thought of a spherical mirror. Now, you say that metal walls can make problems. So, I suggested that maybe you can think of better walls. That's all.

Comment: Ruslan's question is perfectly simple to answer, but the OP does need to specify which scenario they mean (as in my original comment).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I mean, of course, two particles moving inside the box. If the nucleus is centered, we effectively have the usual equation for hydrogen atom in center of mass frame, clearly separable into spherical harmonics and confluent hypergeometric function. Why I'm thinking that the two-particle problem might have a solution is because in classical case this problem can be piecewise-analytically solved between the collisions of some of the particles with the hard wall. Maybe this solubility is also present in quantum case.